# CMake override libraries from find_package

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm running `find_package(OpenCV, REQUIRED)` to locate a library. It's installed on the build system and the target system, however the target is slightly different in that one part of the library is not available.

So when building, I get back linker flags like -lfoo -lbar. However, bar isn't available on the target machine and I'm not using it anywhere in the application. Of cource, since it was linked in, the runtime linker complains that it cannot be found.

Is there anyway to override the libraries linked in with find_package? I'll probably just do a string replace type of solution, though I'd be thankful for any help there too since I'm a CMake novice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can remove undesired libraries from `OpenCV_LIBRARIES` variable:

```
list(REMOVE_ITEM OpenCV_LIBRARIES bar)
```

Alternatively, you can read FindOpenCV.cmake source to check if it supports COMPONENTS keyword.